# Beginner Question: Get 2 Reference Voltages for Comparator using Voltage Regulators

Tags: voltage-regulator, comparator, voltage-reference

I'm working on a project where I have a 12 V voltage supply. I need reference voltages of 4.5 V and 3 V which will be each be used as the Vref for a comparator. I am aware that I shouldn't use a divider to split these voltages. I wanted to use voltage regulators to do so, but I am not sure exactly how to get 2 reference voltages using regulators. I am very much a beginner, so simple explanations/guidance would be appreciated greatly!

Edit:

First attempt at regulation, resistors not selected correctly

[image]

Comment: 4.5v and 3v aren't that common, so use an adjustable regulator like the lm317, and dial it to exactly the output voltage you want.

Comment: Yes, I plan to use adjustable regulators, but if I need 2 reference voltages, do I need to use 2 regulators? Would these be connected in parallel to the voltage source?

Comment: you could switch a single 317 between 2 voltages by shorting a feedback resistor, but that's going to lower precision.  12 goes into both, gnd goes into both, 4.5v comes out one, 3v out the other. You might want to buy a module that has all the terminals, capacitors and a trim potentiometer in one stable, heatsinked, and easy-to-use piece, they can be had for 1usd...

Comment: Hmm, now that i think about it, you actually could use a voltage divider since your comparator draws no current from the inputs. Only downside is that 12v fluctuations will scale down, whereas an LM317 will keep it very stable.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am worried about. I need the reference voltage to be exactly equal to 4.5 and 3 V.

Comment: I have added a picture that shows what I think I should be doing (the resistor values will be tuned)

Comment: LM317 is OK, but it is not designed to be a reference. You may also like to consider this:TL431 / TL432 Precision Programmable Reference - TL431
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl431.pdf?ts=1611715897510&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F. I have been using it for a couple of my ADC related projects and need more precise analog voltage references. So far so good.

Comment: "Exactly" is not a useful statement of the requirement. Within 1 volt? Within 0.1 volt? within 0.1%? The cost (and at some point the skill required) will increase greatly the closer the values have to be.

Comment: I would like the measurement within 0.1 volts, and the supply voltage may vary by order 1 V

Comment: For really small current loads like comparators and non lab-accuracy purposes(which it sounds like would suit you) I've had decent luck with just 7805 or L7805.  It's a wasteful circuit, but what you do is look at your op amp input or whatever you're feeding your reference to, and figure out how strong (low resistance from input to ground) of a voltage divider you need to produce that output current accurately, and figure out based on that how much power you'd waste total.  That tells you whether you need a better method.

Comment: I am 80% sure that you are making a beginner's mistake of specifying a not very flexible 4.5V reference. Usually 4.1V (approx 4.096V) is the optimal engineering trade off and cost beneficial. Perhaps you can let us know the design part on 4.5V requirement and we can see if there is a work around with 4.1V. Cheers.

Comment: [MCP1541](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/21653c.pdf) does 4.096V fixed .... [TLV431B](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv431.pdf?ts=1611746974987&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) is nice adjustable shunt reg, low power, 0.5% "initial accuracy"

Comment: I am comparing to a current sensor. The comparator needs to trigger if the voltage exceeds 3 V, which will trigger a shutdown circuit.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, 0.1V out of 4.5V is +/-2% or so. So a regulator with a 5% tolerance won't be good enough unless you trim it.

Here is one way (Circuitlab is declining to work, so screen cap will have to do)

[image]

R1 can be 5%, the others should be at least 1%. The precision resistor values are from the E96 series, so they can be easily purchased.

U1 is drawn as a zener diode, but it actually is a precision trimmed [shunt reference](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm4040-n.pdf?ts=1611671073234&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLM4040-N%253Fqgpn%253Dlm4040-n) IC.

You could replace R1/U1 with a series 5V regulator or reference provided the performance was good enough when you calculate the error budget.